# Why doesn't Lord Krishna give Moksha to everyone?

Tags: krishna, moksha

If Krishna wants, he can give Moksha to everyone.

Bhagavad Gita [18.66](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/18/66):

> sarva-dharmān parityajya
>
> mām ekaṁ śaraṇaṁ vraja
>
> ahaṁ tvāṁ sarva-pāpebhyo
>
> mokṣayiṣyāmi mā śucaḥ
>
> **Meaning:-** Abandon all varieties of religion and just surrender unto Me. I shall deliver you from all sinful reactions. Do not fear.

By his grace, he can free anyone from sins. Why his grace will only fall if one surrenders to him? Why doesn't he give Moksha to everyone? Because everyone's ultimate goal is Moksha so just give them Moksha.

Ramakrishna Paramahamsa [said](http://www.belurmath.org/gospel/chapter08.htm):

> **There is another class of devotees, known as Kripasiddha, that is to say, those on whom the grace of God descends all of a sudden and who at once attain His vision and Knowledge.**  Such people may be likened to a room that has been dark a thousand years, which, when a lamp is brought into it, becomes light immediately, not little by little.

So it is possible that every single creature could get Moksha just by the grace of God.

Comment: Good question! Why doesn't Krishna want to give Moksha to Everyone! Because they don't want it. Simple as that. We don't want it. The moment you say 'I really want it', it will come to you. Think of it like this, you are the mother, and your child is playing with its toys in the living room. So long as it is happily playing with its toys, you don't interfere. But the moment it starts crying and calling you, You RUN to its side. Similarly, we are all too busy with worldly life for God. This is taken from the teachings of Sri Ramakrishna. Good luck.

Comment: @Sai If we don't want Moksha then forcefully give us that! We are under ignorance so simply remove our ignorance and take us to the world of Brahman. The child didn't knew about toys so why give him that in the first place? If the toys have been given to the child then take them away, the child will cry for toys for 1 day, 2 day but on 3rd day, he won't cry. If we are too busy with worldly life, then remove this worldly life. If the ocean is covered then no wave can come, similarly the formless won't take any form, Nirguna won't become Saguna, unmanifested won't become manifested

Comment: @Sai and the universe won't be created, no ignorance would be there, no Maya will exist. If the cause is withdrawn then the effect would cease to exist.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Neither there was a creation nor destruction. It was just maya. Consciousness (Brahman) alone is there and Consciousness alone is truth. It's like we are in sleep and when we wake up, world with Brahma, Vishnu  and Rudra disappear just as dream disappears. Read Yoga Vasistha.It will clear your doubts.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yeah but why we are in sleep? Remove the sleep, remove all dreams so illusion will automatically disappear. By the way, I will read Yoga Vasistha.

Comment: If He gave moksha to everyone then the play will be done! This is all His playing about. He doesn't want the play to finish, it goes on eternally. The Lord wants to play!

Comment: In Bhagvad Gita, Karmayog chapter Shri Krishna has said that to maintain the material body, one have to work according to his/her quality. It means, if we will do some work, either it will be good or bad. So, the people with bad karma are not eligible to get Moksha. In other perspective, if all people get Moksha, then what will remain in this `Sristi`? Nothing because, after getting `moksha` the `jeevatma` will be freed from reborn.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Yeah, Sri Ramakrishna mentioned a lot about that, he always used to say that it is all Kali's play. But I don't want to play. I don't want to play anymore.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Well if nothing will remain in this Sristi, then that's good news! Eligible or not eligible, give everyone Moksha and everything will be settled.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda swamiji could you please tell me;why He instructs in geeta on how to get out of this world if He doesnt want the play to stop?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Good question 'If we dont want moksha then forcefully give us that!'. Why would he want to force you into something you don't want! The best way to understand is watching a movie or playing a computer game. This is a lengthy topic, however, in brief. Imagine a movie where before starting the director comes and says 'guys movie is over, please exit the theater'. You would not appreciate it right? The good, the bad, the hero, the comedian, the villain, the heroin, its all part of the experience! :)

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande He gives instruction for those that have tired of the play. Not to worry, 99% of people are not tired of the play. Most people ignore the Gita entirely so the play goes on and on.

Comment: Then there will be no point in existing .He does not want us (Humans) to be controlled by him instead he want and gives every one the chance to write his /her own fate and achieve it by your own efforts just keep him in ur mind every time

Answer (score 4):

Before looking into the answer let us first look at few questions.

1. **Why did Government create prison houses?**
2. **Government has the power to release all the prisoners.Why doesn't the head of Government release all of them?**

Many Vaishnav acharyas compare this material world(that includes different heavenly and hellish planets) to a prison house.

**So why was this material world created?**

**Actually This material world is eternal it was never created.(BG 13.20)**

> Material nature and the living entities should be understood to be
>   beginningless. Their transformations and the modes of matter are
>   products of material nature.

For those who are envious of GOD are sent to this world. We can see that everybody here wants to lord it over material nature; some one wants to be a master of his family, someone master of his country, master of his job etc. But in reality Krishna is the master of entire cosmic creation. I discuss this matter in more detail in my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13853/why-man-is-mortal-irrespective-of-good-or-bad-activity/13855#13855) .

**Why Doesn't Krishna grant liberation to all?**

The living entities in this world may be broadly classified in 2 categories.

1. those who are engaged in sense gratification(serving the illusory
   energy of krishna )
2. Those who are engaged in service of God(PATH OF SELF REALIZATION)

And Krishna says:

> As all surrender unto Me, I reward them accordingly. Everyone follows
>   My path in all respects, O son of Pṛthā.

So if someone wants to serve external illusory energy of GOD; Krishna grants his desire and sends such person to this world/or keeps the person in this world.

Basically God doesn't interfere with out free will(I discuss this free will in my above linked answer).Because there is no point in showing a gun to a girl and asking her to say 'I Love You' :D . In that circumstance anyone will say as you dictate. God does not impose himself on us. We came here by our wish so he wants us to return on our own wish.

So point here is :**He sent us to this world because we wanted to come here.**

**How do we know that Krishna respects our will?**

At the end of Geeta Krishna Says :

> Thus I have explained to you knowledge still more conﬁdential.
>   Deliberate on this fully, and then do what you wish to do.

So here he is not forcing Arjuna to carry out His(Krishna's) will instead asks Arjuna to do as he wishes to.

In addition I would also mention a small story(I guess its a folk tale but i'm not sure):

**Story goes roughly like this:**
Once sage Narada was visiting different places of pilgrimage on earth where he saw many people engaged in worshiping Vishnu. He was bewildered as to how come Vaikuntha is so vacant. These people are so pious they must be in Vaikuntha.

So when he reached Vaikuntha He asked Lord Narayana about it. lord said 'You can bring all of them here if they wish to'. Narada became happy and came back on earth.

He asked people if they desire to come to Vaikuntha. Half of them did not know what Vaikuntha was and others were just not interested since they were deeply attached to their kinsmen etc. then Narada realized what is the condition of living entities of this world.

**P.S.**: I have given a crude example of Prison houses built by government. SO Based on criminal actions of person judiciary system send a person to prison. however Krishna sees intentions and desires and accordingly places a person in different abode.Krishna being the [supersoul](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/13/23) in everyone's heart is aware of the intentions of all living beings.

> Yet in this body there is another, a transcendental enjoyer, who is
>   the Lord, the supreme proprietor, who exists as the overseer and
>   permitter, and who is known as the Supersoul.

**Edit1:**

**Great Acaryas have descended in this world over period of time.
Someone might ask are Acharyas(great Vedantist such as Shankara,Ramanuja,Madhav etc.) envious of GOD?**

In answer we can look back to our example of Prison House. Sometimes police in-charge, minister or in some cases even head of state may enter a prison to see that administration is going on well. However it is not wise to think that they are prisoners.

Basically there are two types of living entities

1. Nitya-Mukta(Eternally liberated)
2. Nitya-baddha(Eternally Bound)

So Most of great Acaryas(Not all may be) are considered as Nitya-Mukta or are considered as incarnation of God.

They descent by their own will for delivering the fallen souls.Ex. if above mentioned great acaryas had never descended to this world we would have never been able to discuss this matter as we are doing right now.

**I wish to be liberated. Why am I still in this world and Not liberated?**

Again revisiting our example.If prisoner says 'release me'; will authorities release him? obviously answer is 'No'.

To release a prisoner there are 2 main factors.

1. What is the punishment give?has he served the period?
2. Has he transformed;and is all criminal mentality Gone?

So here in our case above point 1 will correspond to:

How much baggage of Karama do you carry? **You have to repeat cycle of birth and death untill you have suffered or enjoyed for your past karma.**

2nd Point will correspond to 
Do we really have sincere desire for liberation and are we really trying hard for that?

Krishna Says(BG 9.34):

> Engage your mind always in thinking of Me, become My devotee, offer
>   obeisances to Me and worship Me. Being completely absorbed in Me,
>   surely you will come to Me.

Krishna repeats above verse in [18.65](http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/18/65)

And finally He says :

> Abandon all varieties of religion and just surrender unto Me. I shall
>   deliver you from all sinful reactions. Do not fear.

So we have to examine ourself across these factors. We just cant say 'oh!I want moksh' and that Krishna will come and liberate you.

That is like saying 'Oh Krishna!Please make me rich' and expecting that he will come and make you rich then and there.
This is common sense. After you cultivate a plant you have to wait for long time till that plant becomes tree and gives you fruits.This is simple law of nature. And being in this world we are bound by these laws of nature.

**Edit2:**

I also disagree* with the statement that according to you Ramkrishna makes:

The reason being;if Krishna gave liberation to anyone randomly(withou any qualification); then that would mean that Krishna is biased.

**But it is confirmed in Geeta and Vedanta sutra that Krishna is not biased towards anyone.For Him everyone is equal.**

note: * I disagree if he meant that without any qualification moksha is given. Sometimes it may seem like a person is all of the sudden liberated, but we do not know of his pious credit and spiritual advancement.

Comment: "For those who are envious of GOD are sent to this world" Going by your statement, are Vaishnav Acharyas envious of God as well? "So if someone wants to serve external illusory energy of GOD" Why did Krishna create illusory energy? If he didn't create it, then nobody would know about it. "He sent us to this world because we wanted to come here" Now I want to go back immediately but I'm still here. You said Krishna is the master of the cosmic creation then why doesn't he removes the desires that bind us to this material world?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria some great Vaishnav Acaryas(and non-Vaishnava) are either incarnation of God or are nitya mukt atma(who are not bewildered). They descent by their own will to deliver the people.ex. Shankaracharya,Ramanujacarya etc.Also Krishna descents; does not mean that he is envious of himself.Why Krishna descents with his associates is explained in 4th chpt of Geeta.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria BTW in my answer i never said that 'If you want moksh immediately Krishna will grant it.' Once you come in this world you are bound by laws of material nature.You cannot put a seed in soil and say 'Oh i want fruits immediately'.That is against laws of nature.

Comment: "You have to repeat cycle of birth and death until you have suffered or enjoyed for your past karma" Why was karma there in the first place? Now that there is karma, then remove all of this so no action, no reaction. "And being in this world we are bound by these laws of nature" Then remove all laws of nature. You said Krishna is the master of the universe then he can give Moksha even if we don't want it.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria you are going off topic. your original question was 'why Krishna does not give moksha?'.That i have already answered.The question of Moksha comes once person has already fallen in this material world.Then in comment you asked 'why Krishna created the world?'(this actually is a differnt question)but I have answered that as well. Now you areasking why there are laws governing that material world?..I personally feel that you should ask a question separately.

Comment: example if my question is 'what does some xyz acarya say about some abc verse?'...If some one tells what that acarya says;then that is to be considered as answer. But if you want to know 'why he says so about that verse?'...then that is a diffrnt question.This is my opinion.However Im fully able to answer your most recent query as well.But im sure u will go in a loop and I fear you will at a point ask me 'why there is god?' :D

Comment: Well you said Krishna is the master of the cosmic universe so he is capable enough to give Moksha to all no matter how bad karmas a person has accrued. You gave an example of prison but why Krishna allowed that person to do the bad action. He can stop people from taking birth and directly send them to Moksha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41965/discussion-between-vishal-prabhu-lawande-and-chinmay-sarupria).

Answer (score 2):

I think Shree Krishna expects us to do the right things and live our life, do our karma according to  **Shreemad Bhagvad Geeta श्रीमद भगवद्गीता** as told by himself. And through our kama , finally to come to him. So he wont offer moksha to everyone , but wants everyone to achive it themself by following his teachings and ways.

> **तस्मात सर्वेषु कालेषु माम अनुस्मर युध्य च ।**
>
> मय्य अर्पितमनॊबुद्धिर माम एवैष्यस्य असंशयः॥
>
> श्रीमद भगवद गीता . Chapter 8 shlok 7
>
> tasmāt—therefore; sarveṣu—always; kāleṣu—time; mām—unto Me; anusmara—go on remembering; yudhya—fight; ca—also; mayi—unto Me; arpita—surrender; manaḥ—mind; buddhiḥ—intellect; mām—unto Me; eva—surely; eṣyasi—will attain; asaṁśayaḥ—beyond a doubt.
>
> **Meaning:-** Therefore, Arjuna, you should always think of Me in the form of Kṛiṣhṇa and at the same time carry out your prescribed duty of fighting. With your activities dedicated to Me and your mind and intelligence fixed on Me, you will attain Me without doubt.

Comment: "I think Shree Krishna expects us to do the right things" That is my question! Why he want us to do right things when he simply can give Moksha?

Comment: The problem is Government is not omnipotent, or omnipresent or omniscient or morally perfect

Answer (score 2):

<sub>While visiting the site after a while, I really liked this Q. I would also agree with [@Sai's answer comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13889/why-doesnt-lord-krishna-give-moksha-to-everyone#comment33351_13889). At the same time your counter arguments (to that comment & other answers) are quite interesting and those led me to write this down. Sometimes, we ask something as a way of expression. Deep down we know that, we don't want an answer from other sources, but via same place from where the question actually came: "the deep down". This answer might act as a helper.</sub>

> "If '*Krishna*' wants, he can give Moksha to everyone. By '*his*' grace, '*he*' can free anyone from sins. Why '*his*' grace will only fall if one surrenders to '*him*'? Why doesn't '*he*' give Moksha to everyone?"

In your queries, I have highlighted "Krishna", "he", "his", "him" etc.. If you think the personal form of VAsudeva Krishna, who was a YAdava prince, ruled in Mathura & Dwarka, married to Rukmani, cousin of PAndava, spoke Gita -- as a "giver of Moksha", then I fear that it's a wrong perception. Of course that body which lived for 100+ years was divine & godly, but that body was/is/will-be NOT responsible for the Moksha received by various *Jiva*s (includes him) before, during & after his time in earth or other planets.

While perceiving "God": the Vaishnava-s refer -- "Krishna", many prefer -- "Shiva", Advaitans refer -- "Brahman", Muslims/Sufi-s as -- "Allah" & so on.
During Gita, that ultimate was referred as "Me". But we innocently connect it to Krishna, because he spoke. Plz refer [**Understanding "Me"**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/12189/1049).
In summary, *"Atma", "Turiya", "Moksha", "Leela", "Akarma (in Karma)"* are different names of that "Me" only.

**What is *Moksha*?**

There are various understandings of ultimate liberation. One should choose, whichever suits.
Whatever Krishna described as *Atma*, realizing that itself is Moksha. Some describe it as *(nirvikalpa) SamAdhi* as well. Again, what is that?
IMO, the best objectification of this state was done in Buddhism as attaining [*ShunyatA*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9A%C5%ABnyat%C4%81) (*NirvAna*). The complete void-ness, nothingness is the true nature of God. The same has been repeated in many indirect ways in Gita, and once in a direct way:

> <sub>BG 8.21 — **What is called as "Unmanifested Indestructible", that's known as the final state (*Moksha*)**. Gaining which [one] doesn't return, is "My" transcendental destination.</sub>

At 1st, it appears strange to term "God = Nothing", but that has been implied in Gita again & again. From *SAmkhya* school of thinking, "Nothing" finally remains when you apply [Neti Neti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neti_neti) on everything which comes your way.
Apart from Gautam Buddha, the modern day Yogis like Ramana Maharshi, Osho ([see here](http://www.osho.com/iosho/library/read-book/online-library-nothingness-attainment-empty-b62d0897-33a?p=c45b9abd157a615d0eab25dfe044d8e1)) & Jaggi Vasudev have also advocated this "nothingness" as the true nature.

> *"Why his grace will only fall if one surrenders to him? Why doesn't 'he' give Moksha to everyone?"*

Probably you think, "If we surrender to God, then God grants Moksha", where God & Moksha are different.
But as I described above, the "Me" (God) & "Moksha" are just same. It simplifies that: "One who surrenders to 'Me', gets 'Me'" or "One who surrenders to 'Moksha', gets 'Moksha'".

One may counter argue that, why that surrender-ship (*SharanAgati*) is not coming automatically?
Well, that happens too. Ultimately all gets *Moksha* by merging into that "Me" during the end of universe.

> <sub>BG 9.7 — O son of Kunti, all elementary world becomes "My" nature at end of cycle(*Kalpa*); Again I create them at the beginning of the cycle.</sub>

So at least half of the time (night), everything remains in the state of Moksha for sure. But I believe, your question is during the other half (day). Hence root of your queries is:

> *"Why shouldn't state of Moksha persist straight away?"*

Well, actually it does! What we (ignorantly) call our "self" is just a minute part of the *Prakruti* - a dumb interaction of materials. The true "self" is Moksha ("Me") only.
The whole chapter [BG 13](http://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/) is dedicated to this & hopefully answers your question.
There are 3 entities which relates all of us:

1. ***Prakruti***: Visible universe constituting *Sattva, Rajas, Tamas*. All elementary world consists of *Prakruti*. It's also called *mAyA*, because it illusions the timelessness into past, present & future. Body & senses including mind belongs here. This entity completely differentiates you & I.
2. ***Purusha***: The enjoyer or consumer. Also called as *Kshetragya* according to BG 13.2. It witnesses (otherwise dumb) *Prakruti* as the reality. However, what constitutes *Purusha* & how it's different from *Atma* is bit shadowy & ambiguous to me. The closest objectification I have found is *Buddhi* as equivalent of *Purusha*. Refer BG 3.42 & [*Buddhi vs Mann*](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/10799/1049). This entity partially differentiates you & I, as both of our *Purusha*s are Witnesses, but they are witnessing different interactions of *Prakruti*.
3. ***Atma***: The true "self". This is the 'creator'/'sustainer' of both *Prakruti* & *Purusha*. This entity (rather no entity) merges you & I into **same** "Me". i.e. the *ShunyatA*/"nothingness" as discussed before.

> <sub>BG 13.20 — Know that *Prakruti & Purusha*, both are certainly beginning-less; Transformations and *Guna-s (sattva, rajas, tamas)* are known to be possible due to *Prakruti*.</sub>
>   <sub>BG 13.21 — *Prakruti*'s purposes are said to be Activity - Reason - Creation; *Purusha*'s purpose is said to consume happiness & sorrow.</sub>

So when we ask the question, "Why Moksha is not given to everyone straight away?" "Why the Universe is created at first?" "Why all these miseries?" and so on. -- These questions are being raised only due to the interactions of the *Prakruti*'s modes only. Ofcourse, this answer also!
Why are they happening? -- So that the enjoyer termed as *Purusha* inside that body can consume that.

Not only happiness, but the *Purusha* in us wants to enjoy the misery & sorrow as well; Because it still differentiates this sorrow from the happiness. The moment this (sorrow vs happiness) & all other dualities disappears, this *Purusha* also disappears. The disappearance of *Purusha* is called, '*Purusha* being merged to the *ShunyatA*'. The state of nothing-ness is Moksha or *Brahman*.

What *Atma* is doing all the time when the *Purusha* is 'enjoying' the *Prakruti*? -- The *Atma* or "Me" remains unaffected and continues pervading without being spoiled.

> <sub>BG 13.31 — When one realizes that the diversity of elementary world(*Prakruti*) is rooted in the One [which has] expanded, that attains *BrahM*.</sub>
>   <sub>BG 13.32 — Being beginning-less, being formless, the indivisible (0 / n = 0) transcendental "self"(*Atma*) being in body neither does anything nor gets affected, O son of Kunti.</sub>
>   <sub>BG 13.33 — How the space being subtle doesn't get affected, the "self"(*Atma*) being pervading everywhere in the body doesn't get affected.</sub>

Comment: Yes, you are right... before starting of Anu Gita Parva when Arjuna insists Krishna to retell Bhagvad Gita... then Krishna says " **Param Hi Brahman Kathitam Yogayuktena Tanmaya**"... He tells he was unable to repeat it now because "That time Param Brahman had told it and he was concentrated in higher Yoga"...

Comment: @Tezz, Apparently Arjuna had forgotten Gita after the war & hence "asked to retell Gita". On this backdrop there is another (unverified) interesting philosophy I came across. To be on the path of Gita, one has to forget it (or any scripture for that matter). Because the knowledge & its illumination also binds the *Jiva* with the *Prakruti*. That's the rare binding created by *Sattva* (BG 14.6). Hence probably, Arjuna forgetting Gita might have been destined for his own liberation.

Comment: Purusha is different from both Buddhi and Manas.  Buddhi and Manas are evolutes of Prakriti which arise when Purushas interact with Prakriti.  I suggest you study Samkhya philosophy for more information.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, According to Gita, only *Mann* is born out of *Prakruti*, but NO mention of -- *Buddhi* also born from *Prakruti*. *Buddhi* is termed higher than *Mann* in BG 3.42. According to *SAmkhya* only, *Purusha* only procreates *Budhhi* when fusions with *Prakruti*. Until this fusion, there is no solid objectification of *Purusha* which differentiates it with *Atma*. On the contrary, BG 8.22 in fact terms *Purusha* & *Atma* as almost same. But we know they are different. Nevertheless, this ambiguity is also specified in my answer. Put a link to that scripture, which says otherwise.

Comment: No, Purusha and Atma are the same, but Buddhi is different.  Again, I suggest that you read about Samkhya philosophy, because the Bhagavad Gita presumes that the audience already knows about the Samkhya framework.   Ishwara Krishna's Samkhya Karika would be a good place to start.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, You assume that, I equate *Buddhi* & *Purusha* as same; despite this line: "Closest objectification I have found is *Buddhi* as equivalent of *Purusha*". Here is my reasoning: *Buddhi* resides between *Mann* & *that*; like how *Purusha* resides between *Prakruti* & *Atma*. Saying *Purusha* & *Atma* as same is ambiguous. Because *Atma* is non-dual, while *Purusha* has duality. When all dualities or separateness disappears from *Purusha*-s, it becomes *Atma*. Instead of keep suggesting, plz post a web-link which supports your assumptions. Else, I close the topic from my side.

Comment: @iammilind OK, if you want a web link here is Ishwara Krishna's Samkhya Karika along with Gaudapada's commentary on it: http://www.universaltheosophy.com/sacred-texts/samkhya-karika/. It goes into great detail about relation between Purusha and Prakriti, and the sequence of evolutes of Prakriti.  It should clarify things for you.

Comment: I agree that Moksha and Brahman are not different but "Brahman = nothing" should be properly interpreted like Brahman can not be known/realized and expressed by Mana and Buddhi. So, I suggest to go with "imperceivable" or "inexpressible" instead of "nothing".