# Is Boon for Moksha grantable?

Tags: gods, moksha, desire

1. Every **Life's goal is Moksha** and it is achieved through various paths.
2. **Penanace were done to get Boons** from God like Power,Wealth,Strength for his Welfare.

**Is Boon for Moksha grantable ?**

Comment: No one ever asked for this boon from any Lord, So it's hard to tell what will be Lord's response on that boon.

Comment: As the Christians say "Ask and ye shall receive." You don't need any special boon.  If you simply surrender to the lotus feet of Sriman Narayana, he will grant you Moksha.

Comment: If it is backed by penance and industry by the jeeva.My mother once told me a story.When Dhruva was walking through the forest to start his tapas he encountered a very old taapasa under a very old tree.The tapasvi inquired after him & was pleased to note that the child was on his way to tapas.He said to Dhruva"Child,Narayana will surely give you darshan.When he does will you please ask him when he would grant me moksha".Dhruva agrees, finishes his tapas and is on his way back. He meets the tapasvi. The tapasvi wants to know if his request to Narayana was conveyed and what His response was. 1/2

Comment: Dhruva is hesitant to reply.Upon insistence, he regretfully says that he did ask and Narayana stated that He would grant the tapasvi mOksha after as many years as each leaf on the tree under which he is doing tapas,falls off & regenerates some n times.(I forget the no. but it is very very large,even so when we calculate cumulatively). Dhruva apologises to the taapasa.But the old man is overjoyed.He says"he is blessed that Narayana agreed to grant mOksha in the 1st place -sooner or later.He did not outright reject his plea.He thanks Dhruva & continues his tapas with renewed vigor& hope. 2/2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Lord Krishna give Moksha to everyone?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13889/why-doesnt-lord-krishna-give-moksha-to-everyone) and [Who gives Moksha](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3563/1049).

Comment: Moksha is never earned. It is always only granted.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Not true, Lord Krishna has specified 2 ways of getting moksha. One from devotion and other from by own efforts in which he/she has to stop making punya and papa income so that they won't get either heaven nor hell. If they won't get either of them then there is no option left but to get moksha. So the person who don't worship any Lord, he/she can also get moksha.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Granting us moksha only if we earn it isn't it ?

Comment: What is the relation between My question and Why Lord Krishna Didn't give Moksha to everyone ?

Comment: @Sakthi No one earns it. The Mundaka U (III.ii.3) says: "This Atman is not to be attained by the study of the Vedas, nor by the highest intellect, nor by much learning. Whom the Atman seeks, he gets the Atman; unto him He discloses His glory." Shankara says one must have an intense hankering. The Atman seeks him who has an intense hankering for the Atman alone.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Thanks friend for clearing the doubt

Answer (score 4):

First of all we need to understand the concept of 84 lakhs of Yonis that a Jiva or soul has to travel through before merging back to Brahman again. And, this merging back is called Moksha.

> **Chaturashitilakshesu** Sarireshu SaririnAm | Na Manushyam VinA Annyatra
>   Tatva GyAnantu Labhyate ||
>
> Among the **84 lakh of Yonis** (wombs) Tatva Gyana (Brahma Gyana,or
>   knowledge of the Self) is achieved only in the human body and not in
>   any other bodies.
>
> **KulArnava Tantram,Chapter 1, Verse 14.**

Now, its  said that unless the Jiva completes its destined journey through all this aforementioned number of Yonis, it is not entitled to get liberated.

That is, it is not entitled to get liberated before completing the full circle.

Read the following discussion that occurs between Lord Shiva and Goddess Chandi in Sri MatrikA Bheda Tantram:

> Sri ChandiKA UvAcha :
>
> AgrAhyam Tava NirmAlyamgrAhyam Karanam Vibho |
>
> MrishA VAkyam MahAdeva Katham Vadasi Yogabhrith ||
>
> ................
>
> Sri ChandikA Devi said :
>
> [ You yourself have said in other Shastras ] that your nirmalya should not be consumed. Being Yogi yourself, how did you utter that lie?
>
> Sri Shankara Uvacha:
>
> **Chaturasitilaksheshu Yonigarthe Tathaiva Hi |
>    Bhramanam Kuruthe Jeevastato Mokshasya BhAjanam ||**
>
> Etanmadhye MahA GyAnam Yafi SyAd Veeravandite |
>   Tada MokkshamvApnoti Bhramanam Kena VA Bhaveth ||
>   Ataeva Maheshani Gupta BhAvam MayA Kritam |
>
> ...........
>
> Lord Shankara said:
>
> **A Jiva gets fit for liberation only after traveling through all the 84
>   lakhs of Yonis and not before that.** Now if Mahagyana (the knowledge of Self) is obtained by it sometime before that
>   then it will be liberated. How will it travel through all the 84 lakhs
>   Yonis then? Hey Devi, that's why i have said that for the purpose of
>   maintaining secrecy.

I have highlighted the portions that are relevant here.

So, IMO, in most cases that boon can't be granted. It will depend on whether that Jiva has completed its destined journey through all the Yonis or not.

God will know very well if the person has completed his destined journey or not. And, if he/she has, only in those cases the boon will be granted.

NOTE: I have assumed that you're asking about attaining Moksha in the current birth only.

Comment: Your answer didn't give the complete answer what OP asked. You said this boon can't be granted before completing the cycle (circle of yoni) But if someone has already completed this cycle then He/She can get this boon or not?

Comment: Yes in that case, he will obviously get the boon, @Rishabh

Comment: But the demons that used to be killed by Lord, they already completed the cycle before got died by Lord's hand?

Comment: @Rishabh Yes, they must have. I don't  know what's happening in the background.

Comment: @Rishabh I have now clarified on the point u raised.

Comment: But still don't know why m not totally convinced with this fact. Because many got moksha in satyuga and treta yuga. Did they complete their cycle that early! Most of the demon got killed just starting of first yuga like Hiranyaksh and some got killed even earlier. But in any case, if this really is true then Why Lord Krishna didn't mentioned about this compulsory cycle while teaching us way of getting moksha in Bhagwat Geeta... Why he said if someone will completely lost in my thought on his death time then even if he is biggest sinful human in the world, even then he will get moksha..

Comment: I thought I already knows about all way of getting moksha coz already read Bhagwat Geeta but this new point that u raised (yoni cycle) was not present in Bhagwat Geeta. SO Bhagwat Geeta is incomplete? I am so much confused.

Comment: I personally don't think that 84 lakh concept is correct because if it was, then all of us would have already got Moksha by now, after all, we are taking different bodies since infinite time.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria He said when we completes 84 laks yoni then we become eligible to get moksha. Doesn't mean all will get moksha after completing those yonies. His mean our all efforts or devotion towards getting moksha is useless until we won't complete yoni circle. Our efforts towards moksha will be started to count only after 84 lakh yoni. But this isn't mention in Lord krishna's Bhagwat Geeta, So I can't fully trust on this theory.

Comment: @Rishabh Its Ok to be not convinced. But your argument that Moksha possible only in Kali Yuga and not in Satya or Treta does not make sense. Coz we have to consider that creation is an endless and beginingless cycle. And i think this 84 lakh is mentioned in other Scriptures as well like the Puranas.

Comment: **But in any case, if this really is true then Why Lord Krishna didn't mentioned about this compulsory cycle while teaching us way of getting moksha in Bhagwat Geeta.** Lol i just wonder how the people of Satya , Treta and most part of Dwapara used to live without BG .and considering the fact that they were more intelligent, more powerful and more DharmiK.@Rishabh

Comment: **SO Bhagwat Geeta is incomplete?** Do u think it is complete?? In what sense it is complete? Even after Vedas we have so many Scriptures. So were not the Vedas complete that we need so many of the  others? @Rishabh

Comment: @Rickross By complete I mean was, complete about info regarding moksha. I means Lord Krishna told us all possible way of getting moksha in Bhagwat Geeta. Then why He didn't tell us about role of yoni cycle for moksha? Why he kept hidden and disclose every thing else regarding moksha. Why told us everything about moksha except one point? That's why it's hard to convinced about this fact of your!

Comment: **That's why it's hard to convinced about this fact of your!** That's not my fact i am simply quoting from one of the Scriptures. You need to understand that besides BG there are thousands of other Scriptures. Wher BG has 700 slokas KT has 2400+ slokas. And, originally it is believed that it had 1, 25000 slokas. So, my point is there are a whole lot of Scriptures besides BG . Its a different thing that most people of Kali Yuga only know about BG but don't know about the others.. Also, i am not writing answers to convince you or any other persons. I just post whatever i read in the Scriptures.

Comment: @Rickross Friend Now if Mahagyana (the knowledge of Self) is obtained by it sometime before that then it will be liberated. How will it travel through all the 84 lakhs Yonis then? **Hey Devi, that's why i have said that for the purpose of maintaining secrecy**    WHAT IS THE SECREACY AND WHAT IS THE PURPOSE FOR MAINTAINING IT

Comment: @Sakthi Sorry for the late reply. This is about drinking the Shiva padodakam (SP). The water, milk, honey etc which are poured on the Shiva Lingam are collectively called SP. Now, Lord Shiva supposedly prohibited drinking SP in some Scriptures. The reason is that one who consumes the SP is sure to get Moksha in that life. Even if a Chandala does that he will get liberated. But that will be against natural order. Because not everyone has completed his/her cycle of 84 lakh Yonis journey.

Comment: @Sakthi So, to stop people getting Moksha earlier than when they were supposed to get it, Lord Shiva said that "lie". When confronted by Devi (why did u utter that lie being God ?), Lord Shiva says that since that was said  in order to maintain secrecy so that does not qualify for a lie. Actually all those verses are not relevant to answering ur Q. So, i have highlighted the relevant verses only in my answer

Comment: This is all a myth that all this has been said by Lord Shiva. I believe it was Swami Vivekananda who said that just to make people believe certain texts, they inserted names of Shiva and Shakti like Shiva said to Shakti so that people will believe it.

Comment: Are you an expert or what? I don't need ur opinions on authoritative Tantras like Sri Matrika Bheda etc. And unlike you i am not a blind follower of any scholars, acharyas etc. @ChinmaySarupria

Comment: Haven't you made yourself a blind follower too by using the word "authoritative" before Tantras? :)

Comment: When you don't know about something what's the use of an argument? Do u have even the slightest idea of Tantras? Which are the authoritative Tantrik Texts? Do you have any ideas about it? Then why to discuss? @ChinmaySarupria I am initiated i can not hear Shastra Ninda. I am not allowed to do so. So excuse me.

Comment: And this 84 lakhs of Yonis is mentioned in numerous Agamas. It's a well known concept among Scriptures. Even many Puarans like Garuda mention about it. So, it is not that only Matrika Bheda mentions it. @ChinmaySarupria

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria i will.soon come.up with a new thread in this regard.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Yes i am a blind follower but that of Lord Shiva and Mother Goddess only. I am not at all influenced by any of the so-called Acharyas and similar well-known persons who place their views on Hinduism. Also, sorry if i was rude in my previous comments. Last nite my mood was off :)

Comment: I am a follower of Advaita so for me, the whole world is nothing but a projection so you need not be sorry as I don't see you as a separate entity from the undivided stream of consciousness.

Comment: @Vishvam Saying that demons are killed by Gods; hence, they attain Moksha, is like encouraging people to commit sins, so that they turn into demons, and then get slain by Gods. "Commit enough sins, then you'll become a demon, and then God will give you moksha by killing you". Almost sounds like an easy way out. Even those demons, killed by Lord Krishna, must have had immense punya to be born as demons who would be later killed by Krishna, and then attain moksha