# Why does Brahman not grant moksha to all according to uttara-mimamsa?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, brahma-sutras, vishishtadvaita, dvaita

This question is asked purely in regard to Uttara-mimamsa school, please do not mark this question again as a duplicate of [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/13889/why-doesnt-lord-krishna-give-moksha-to-everyone) question, which this is not. Firstly it is not referring only to Krishna, but to generalized Brahman and this is not asking in the purview of Bhakti interpretations, it is asking uttara mimamsa interpretation of Brahma Sutras, Upanishads and Bhagavath Gita (Prasthana traya).

You can answer from any Uttara Mimamsa school, Advaitha, Vishishtadvaitha or Dvaitha.

This is actually Hindu version of problem of evil by Epicurus.

[image]

Please give the source if you are quoting some scripture

P.S: If you are thinking why do I oppose the sameness of the other question. It is not opposed, but is a subset of the possibilities. It is one of the possible interpretations. If there is already a question asking what are the advantages of wearing blue shirt. And if I ask what are the advantages of wearing clothes, it should not be treated as a duplicate. Last time when I asked this question people thought the same way and marked my question as a duplicate. This is not in opposition to any school.

Comment: How do you know the answer of this school is different as opposed to the info to what you linked as not duplicate?

Comment: It is not opposed, but is a subset of the possibilities. I never said it is opposed.it is one of the possible interpretations. If there is already a question asking what are the advantages of wearing blue shirt. And if I ask what are the advantages of wearing colored shirt, it should not be treated as a duplicate. Last time when I asked this question people thought this same way and marked my question as a duplicate. This is not in opposition to any school. This is trying to look for all the possibilities.

Comment: Since it is generalized question about Brahman and not on Krishna, by definition Brahman is the ultimate and eternal truth and not a super power. You should find truth/Brahman/Moksha on your own. Like how you don't know if a closed jar has water. The jar, water or truth itself will never open it. You have to open and check it yourself. And that is by nature, truth is not affected by you knowing it or not.

Comment: " If there is already a question asking what are the advantages of wearing blue shirt. And if I ask what are the advantages of wearing colored shirt," I feel like your question is a duplicate. I do not see why this school would have a different interpretation.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu How is that a duplicate? That is a generalization. Because there could be answers about the benefit of wearing yellow, green, white and black shirts which go unmentioned and unaddressed. How is it the same question?? I could generalize it even more saying what are benefits of wearing a shirt. Do you see how its different? Again its not this school or that school, its not a different school, it's a super school. Because the sarvashaktahtva, mahashaktathva and sagunathva and nirgunathva are all different.

Comment: @Downvoters, I do not understand why are you downvoting? Please atleast tell me the reason for downvoting. If you think the question is duplicate then you ask me I will clarify why its not, If you are not convinced o ahead and mark duplicate. If you think the question is bad is some way you can downvote, but please do tell me, why its bad so I can correct it. Please do not downvote because you think its duplicate, those are two different functionalities meaning two different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, Epicurus statement can only be equated to the dualistic schools. All monotheistic schools have the problem of evil. There is no evil in the advaita. *Brahma Sutras* 4.4.1 says (https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras):

> (when the Jiva) has attained (the highest light) there is manifestation (of its real nature), as we know from the words 'own'.

and Shankaracharya's commentary on this verse says:

> ...The Sutra...says that the word 'own' shows that Liberation was a pre-existent thing. The Jiva manifests its own nature, i.e., its real nature, which was so long covered in ignorance. This is its attainment of Liberation. It is nothing that is newly acquired.

You are free already. You are not 'granted' freedom. *Astavakra Samhita* says 1.11, "A man who says he is free, is free indeed; a man who says he is bound remains bound. This popular saying is true 'As you think so you become'"

Brahman cannot grant something you already have. You are free already, just realize it...

Comment: It is indirectly avoiding the basic question.So how does it answer the question?

Comment: This is indeed an an excellent answer, but I am afraid I don't understand this completely and may need some help to understand. If the atman inside is already free, why has it not yet acheived liberation? Why is there dukha?

Comment: And I am also curious how dulaistic and qualified monism school explains it

Comment: @ChakrapaniNRao from dualistic viewpoint, God is playful. The evil and the destruction of evil are all His play.If bad does not exist, the glory of Good is not properly revealed.

Comment: @Pratimaputra thanks for replying, but why does put us inside suffering and then show his glory. But why start the play?

Comment: @ChakrapaniNRao The One became many to have this play He as AtmA is enjoying the different tastes of pleasure and pain.

Comment: @ChakrapaniNRao The answer is there in the Devi-Mahatmya(Sri Sri Chandi). You could read chapters 1 and 11 especially.

Comment: @Pratimaputra But one becoming many is not dualistic,it is monism in a way. At best qualified monism.

Comment: @The basic scriptures have all the isms simultaneously.The commentators explain according to the isms,This is true for all our main scriptures:)

Comment: @Pratimaputra correct, but then how do dvaitis and vishitadvaitis explain this?

Comment: "There is no evil in the advaita" This is a drastic statement.

Comment: @LazyLubber that is meant in a philosophical way. Evil exists in world. But world itself exists in maya. Therefore it does not exist. But it is only for the realized. Only after you are realized there is no more evil to you

Comment: This is a great answer. Even though I head heard this point before, this answer for some reason gave me a new paradigm and better understanding of Advaitha.

Thank you Swami Vishwananda